# Establecer la prioridad de una aplicación ya ejecutándose en Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net

Estoy buscando como establecer la prioridad de una aplicación que se ejecuto antes que mi aplicación (ya estaba corriendo) pero todos los ejemplos que veo son de establecer la prioridad de esta siendo iniciada desde mi aplicación o establecer la afinidad de esta.

Hasta ahora lo mejor que he llegado es:

```
For Each Proceso As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("nombre_proceso")
    Proceso = ProcessPriorityClass.High
Next
```

Pero me dice que `ProcessPriorityClass` no puede ser convertido a un `Process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar la propiedad `PriorityClass` del proceso:

```
For Each Proceso As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("nombre_proceso")
    Proceso.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High
Next
```

Esto soluciona el error que te da. Pero no estoy seguro de que consigas cambiar la prioridad del otro proceso de esta manera. Supongo que deberás usar tu aplicación como administrador.

Comment: Estaba bastante cerca

Comment: Digamos que cierto juego debe ser ejecutado desde XLauncher.exe y este iniciara X.exe de manera local. No creo que necesite permisos de Administrador @Pikoh

Comment: @papydeath95 ah ok. Si,la verdad estas muy cerca de la solucion :)